# Having problems trying to load a signed URL from a streaming CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-s3, html5-video, amazon-cloudfront, flowplayer

I am trying to get a streaming cloudfront distribution to work but the video isn't playing.

Initially, I had an `html5 error: unsupported video` error. I amended the ajax datatype to dataType: "video/mp4" and that error is gone. Now, when you click to load the movie, the splash remains in place, but no movie loads.

What I have done is as follows:

1. I have created a Cloudfront Streaming distribution.
2. On the S3 bucket, I have granted Full control to the AWS user and Read access to the Canonical username of the CloudFront Origin Access Identity to the multiple files in the bucket.
3. The bucket is configured as follows: bucketName/video/0002/ and within directory 0002 there the following files:

   - 0002.mp4
   - 0002.webm
   - 0002.ogv
   - 0002-sm.jpg
   - 0002-lg.jpg
   - 0002-pf.jpg

To test it out, I used the code as provided in http://demos.flowplayer.org/scripting/signed-ondemand.html and changed the elements in getsignedurl.php and index.php as needed.

You can see the test here: http://testserver.ergonomiq.net

A second version is here: http://testserver.ergonomiq.net/v2

I need help narrowing down what the issues are so I can get the videos to play?

I have put the code in a gist.

Version 1: https://gist.github.com/alisamii/6660845

Version 2: https://gist.github.com/alisamii/6660827

Comment: Can we see *your* code? You say you've "changed the elements in getsignedurl.php and index.php as needed" but that's kind of vague - what have you changed? What have you left the same? It's possible the demo code is broken, but it's also possible that you've broken it.